# How can I load data from mySQL database via json_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am loading data from my database via json.

```
$data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$file = 'data.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

This means, when I load the data from the database my file `data.json` is updated.

The data.json looks for example like this:

```
[{"id":"40","name":"Monkey","firstname":"Fred","company":"monkeys","street":"monkeystreet 23","plz":"11111","place":"Wonderland","email":"monkey@monkeyland.com","phone":"1111","fax":"1111","cell":"1111,"country":"Monkeyland","url":"","category":""}
```

This works very well on my localhost, but on my server, the file is not beeing updated. 
This means, if I change, "Monkey" into "Bird", in my database it is "Bird" but in the json file it is still "Monkey".

What could cause this problem? I am happy for any help!

Comment: Maybe file/directory has insufficient rights to write, try to check output of  file_put_contents.

Comment: as @Mr_KoKa said also try check file path.with file_exists($filename) function or cache if you use it.

Comment: Yes, the reason was the rights to write of the data.json file. Thank you very much!